# Android emulator virtual microphone doesn't work on macOS

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I activated virtual microphone on `Android emulator` by enabling toggles at the `Extended Controls > Microphone` path in emulator settings but when I start recording audio by Google Assistant and other recording apps to test it, the emulator receives no audio signal from the machine inputs. My operating system is `macOS Catalina 10.15.4` and the Android Studio version is `3.6`. Also, my laptop microphone works correctly and I checked it with an external Headset and other MacBooks but the problem didn't solve. How could I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is the issue got solved? I too got stuck in the same issue.